# C++ how do i override the << operator within a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, overriding, operators

How would i override the `<<` operator within a class? Or be able to print a `vector<byte>` from within a class. My current code looks like

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<byte>& bytes)
{
    if (bytes.size() == 0)
        return os;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes.size()-1; i++)
        os << hex << (int)bytes[i] << " ";
    os << bytes.back();
    return os;
}
```

It’s hanging outside of the class, and only functions outside of the class can `cout <<` and print a `vector<byte>`. I want to be able to print one from within the class.

## Edit 1

I saw some confusion in the part where i sort of mention how i use it, here would be a good example

```
# method 1
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<byte>& bytes)
{
    if (bytes.size() == 0)
        return os;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes.size()-1; i++)
        os << hex << (int)bytes[i] << " ";
    os << bytes.back();
    return os;
}

int main( {
    vector<byte> v = something;
    cout << “Vector Example: ” << v << endl;
}
```

I want to have the top `method 1` in a class, but per some comments, it is impossible. Is there a different way?

## Edit 2

Thought I’d share my revised and working code thanks to @StephanH.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::byte>& bytes)
{
    if (bytes.size() == 0)
        return os;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes.size() - 1; i++)
        os << std::hex<< (int)bytes[i] << " ";
    os << int(bytes.back());
    return os;
}

class MClass
{
    public:
        std::vector<std::byte> smth;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const MClass& obj) {
            std::string ascii = "hello";
            std::vector<std::byte> bytes(ascii.length());
            for (size_t i = 0; i < ascii.length(); i++)
            {
                bytes[i] = static_cast<std::byte>(ascii[i]);
            }

            return stream << bytes;
        }
};

int main() {
    MClass m;
    std::cout<<m;
}
```

Still trying to figure out how to print out whe i do `m.smth`

Comment: I just want to add that I’m pretty new to c++, i started learning 5 days ago but I’m now writing a secure, and more bulkier encryption program.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to compile? Is this class all in one file, or split into a `.h` and `.cpp` file?

Comment: what is a vector<byte> - there is no byte datatype in C++

Comment: @StephanH does https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte not count?

Comment: Oh, ok did not know std::byte - ok a C++ 17 class

Comment: hex is undefined - bytes.back() needs a type conversion

Comment: @RidleyNelson Only the left-hand side of `operator<<` can possibly implement it as a class member method.  Since `std::ostream` is the left-hand side in your example, you can't implement this version of `operator<<` inside your class, it needs to be a separate function. Which is fine. Whatever problem you are having is related to something else that we can't see, since you did not show how you are trying to use it.

Comment: @StephanH see [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex), add `#include <iomanip>` to use it.

Comment: ok, updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not really sure what you want to achieve and in what context your are in. Here is my approach

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include  <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::byte>& bytes)
{
    if (bytes.size() == 0)
        return os;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes.size() - 1; i++)
        os << std::hex<< (int)bytes[i] << " ";
    os << int(bytes.back());
    return os;
}

class MClass
{
    std::vector<std::byte> smth;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const MClass& obj) {
        return stream << obj.smth;
    }
};
```

Comment: Just1 had to look at the`friend` docs, looks amazing, how would i use it?

Comment: Nevermind got it working, i just need to figure out how to make it print out a vector when I do something like `cout << MClass.myvector;` or `cout << MClass.vec;`